# android: streaming video programmatically that prioritizes video quality than file compression

Tags: video, stream

Hi I would like to know if there are any ways to stream a raw video footage from an android device that prioritizes video quality over file compression? i've tried doing so with webrtc, and clearly the video quality is reduced. I wish to see an increase in network bandwidth usage through streaming using high quality footage (i.e. 4K). are there programmatically alternatives?

Comment: Can you just set a higher bitrate?

Comment: i am streaming 4K from an android phone, but the frame rate is consistently reduced (i.e. from 60-> 5). The bit rate used are no more than 5 Mbps

Comment: But, can you change the bitrate?